# Android edittext with a static string

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I am working on an app where the user inserts his/her name and i will be displayed in a textview.

```
package com.opgaveet.buttonlistener;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText edit;
    TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your name has been submitted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                String name = edit.getText().toString();

                text.append(name);

            }
        });
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This code work fine, no issues there, but it only displays the name that has been inserted. Is there a method to also display "Welcome *name inserted*" instead of just the name, when the name has been submitted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply concatenate the "Welcome" part, something like this:

```
text.append("Welcome " + name);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you'll want to do is use a string in your strings.xml file with a marker in that string which will be replaced.

Create a string in your strings.xml file:

```
<string name="welcome_text">Welcome %s inserted</string>
```

Now in your code do this:

```
text.append(String.format(getString(R.string.welcome_text), name);
```

You can also just do

```
getString(getString(R.string.welcome_text), name);
```

More info here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
String name = "Welcome " + edit.getText().toString();`
```

or:

```
text.append("Welcome" + name);`
```

Answer (score 1):

TO append data of same textview. Create a textview and string like this.

**String:** `<string name="welcome">Welcome</string>`

**Textview**

```
 android:id="@+id/text"
 android:text="@string/welcome"
```

In **Activity** set like this.

```
txt_welcome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
txt_welcome.setText(txt_welcome.getText().toString()+" "+USERNAME);
```